# C iterate by words in file

Tags: c

I try to write a function that receives an input file path, an output path and two strings (s1, s2) and replaces all occurrences of s1 in the input file with s2.

I tried:

```
replace("input.txt", "output.txt", "to", "code");


int replace(const char *input_file, const char *output_file, const char *s1, const char *s2){
    FILE *fbr;
    FILE *fbw;
    char buff[strlen(s1)+1];
    fbr = fopen(input_file, "r");
    fbw = fopen(output_file, "w");
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fbr)) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(fbr, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
        fgets(buff, strlen(s1)+1, fbr);
        fseek(fbr, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
        if(strcmp((char*)buff, s1) == 0){
            fprintf(fbw, "%c", c);
        }else{
            fprintf(fbw, "%s", s2);
        }
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }
}
```

the problem is I don't succeed to use fseek to back the length of the word minus 1 after the fgets and I get infinite loop

Comment: Very important to know: The [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an ***`int`***. Which compares very well to the ***`int`*** value `EOF`. A `char` value might not compare as well to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: On another couple of notes: You should always check what [`fgets`] returns (you don't really need that `fgetc` and `fseek` calls). And remember that it will add the newline in the buffer if it's read. And that if the full line doesn't fit in the length specified in the call, it will not read a full line (the remaining line will be waiting in the input buffer to be read next time).

Comment: Keep a ring buffer of size equal to the length of s1.  Fill it and output s2 whenever it matches.

Comment: gal leshem, Curios, why `L` with `fseek(fbr, -1L, SEEK_CUR);` versus `fseek(fbr, -1, SEEK_CUR);`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear why you are seeking.  Do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
        void *rv = malloc(s);
        if(rv == NULL) {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return rv;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if( argc < 3 ) {
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Insufficient arguments");
        }
        size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
        int c;
        char *buf = xmalloc(len);
        char *e = buf + len;
        char *s = buf;
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                if( s == e ) {
                        if( ! strcmp(buf, argv[1])) {
                                fputs(argv[2], stdout);
                                s = buf;
                        } else {
                                fputc(*buf, stdout);
                                memmove(buf, buf + 1, len - 1);
                                s -= 1;
                        }
                }
                *s++ = c;
        }
        if( s != buf ) {
                fwrite(buf, 1, s - buf, stdout);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The memmove here is pretty inefficient and ugly, but it does the job.  The main point is: don't `seek`.  Read what you need, and keep track of it.  But it's pretty trivial to get rid of the memmove:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
        void *rv = malloc(s);
        if(rv == NULL) {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return rv;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if( argc < 3 ) {
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Insufficient arguments");
        }
        size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
        int c;
        char *buf = xmalloc(len);
        char *s = buf;
        char *m = argv[1];
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                if( (*s++ = c) == *m ) {
                        if( *++m == '\0' ) {
                                fputs(argv[2], stdout);
                                s = buf;
                                m = argv[1];
                        }
                } else {
                        fwrite(buf, 1, s - buf, stdout);
                        s = buf;
                        m = argv[1];
                }
        }
        if( s != buf ) {
                fwrite(buf, 1, s - buf, stdout);
        }
        return 0;
}
```